# Mutual Information in an Binary Erasure Channel

Tags: information-theory

Imagine a Binary Erasure Channel as depicted on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_erasure_channel).

One equation describing the mutual information is following:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
    I(x;y)  &=& H(x) - H(x|y) \\
     &=& H(x) - \left(P(y=0) \cdot 0 + P(y=\varepsilon) \cdot H(x) +P(y=1) \cdot 0\right)
\end{array}
$$

Why is it $P(y=\varepsilon) \cdot H(x)$ and not $P(y=\varepsilon) \cdot H(x|y=\varepsilon)$?

Comment: There is something strange with your equations. Why a y=?, why are there multiplications by 0? Consider rewriting the equations using [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know that $Y=\varepsilon$, then you cannot say anything about $X$. Because the erasure could have been the channel output of both $X=0$ and $X=1$. Therefore knowing $Y=\varepsilon$, does not change our uncertainty of $X$ and $H(X|Y=\varepsilon)=H(X)$.

To give a mathematical reasoning behind this, let's start with following:
$$
\mathbb P(X=0\mid Y=\varepsilon)=\frac{\mathbb P(X=0)\mathbb P(Y=\varepsilon|X=0)}{\mathbb P(Y=\varepsilon)}
$$
Now suppose that $\mathbb P(X=0)=p$, we have:
$$
P(Y=\varepsilon)=\mathbb P(Y=\varepsilon|X=0)\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb P(Y=\varepsilon|X=1)\mathbb P(X=1)=p_e \,p+p_e\, (1-p)=p_e
$$
Therefore:
$$
\mathbb P(X=0\mid Y=\varepsilon)=\frac{p \cdot p_e}{p_e}=\mathbb P(X=0)
$$
This shows that :
$$
H(X|Y=\varepsilon)=H(X)
$$